# Best way to design webpages in Visual Studio 2015 using ASP.net 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm a beginner to web design in Visual Studio and wanted to know what the best workflow is for web design in Visual Studio. From what I can see currently ,based on other tutorials, it seems that i just coding in the cshmtl and then run the site to see how it looks. Is this the only way, or are there other tools (like blend for xaml) for doing design in Visual Studio for webpages?

Comment: No. for MVC, you write HTML markup for the design you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net MVC, the views can use 2 different view engines.

1. ASPX
2. Razor

Razor is one of the preffered view engines for creating MVC views. Here NO Drag and Drop controls are available.
You need to write explicit HTML helpers which will be a big pain to understand initially.

But the Flexibility that Razor View engine provides is better than aspx.

Answer (score -1):

you can use bootstrap or for example kendo,I recommend to use bootstrap, it is easy to use and has a lot of features that may help you,see the link..
http://getbootstrap.com/